# How to change fa-icon size in flexdashboard value box?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

Is it possible to change the size of the fa-icons in a a flexdashboard? The caption text overlaps with the icon and is even more of an issue when a numeric value is of the order 10^4 or greater.

It's not a huge issue but I think it will be more aesthetically pleasing if I can reduce the icon size somehow? I have tried to introduce a line break to the caption using \n but this does not work. I would rather reduce icon size than value size.

Screenshot attached. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have just used different icons instead. I have gone with narrower icons that do not overlap with any caption or value characters. Seems like the easiest solution for now.

Comment: please mention how you did it? code??

Comment: In the `flexdashboard::valueBox()` function, I just used a different icon defined by the argument `icon = "fa-book"`